# Minecraft Bedrock Command block selecting a target with coordinates syntax help?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am playing on my own bedrock realm with the non java version of Minecraft.  I wish to let my kids change their game mode to creative as survival is the default but I don’t want to grant the OP permissions as they tend to start doing things to each other with OP commands and chaos ensues.

I have tried many variations along the same theme of having a pressure plate that triggers a hidden command block 3 blocks below.  I would rather not have to go down the route of boxing in the pressure plate and using a proximity selector.

So I am trying to get this very simple command to work:
`gamemode s @p[44.70,63.00,31.49]`

I have tried with and without brackets, with and without commas but everything so far throws the same exception.  `Syntax error: Unexpected "44.70": at "mode s @p[>>44.70<<,63.00,61.`
This is the same error if I try `@a` or `@e`.  Obviously, I'm doing something wrong with my syntax I just don't know what.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Sorry if this has been asked before,  I did search and found a lot of questions that were very close but none answered this with how to use coords as a selecter and the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selector arguments are in a `key=value` format, so you'll need to add `x=`, `y=`, and `z=` before the values.

You'll also need to specify a radius (`r`) from those coordinates to select players within.

The following command should work:

```
gamemode s @p[x=44.70,y=63.00,z=31.49,r=1]
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel very silly now.  I am sure I read the need for x= etc was removed as in /tp 00 00 00.  But I guess i dreamt that.  Your correction worked perfectly.  Back to school for me.